# Loading Data from CSV to Neo4j

Tags: python, csv, neo4j, cypher

I have data that looks like

```
Bob             Joe           Nathan

4              5               4
3              6               111
3              3               3
111            3               4
5              2
```

But I have about 300 columns of 'Names' and the numbers are 'Attributes' in a CSV. How would I go about loading all this data into neo4j without typing in all the 'Names' and 'Attributes' and linking them to eachother? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you saying you have a separate CSV file that looks different than what you have shown? Show the top 5 rows of that file in your question.

Comment: The data I have linked here is a representation of what the data looks like

Comment: What should be the "Names" column in the resultant nodes? A node label? A property? And the numbers?

Comment: For example: the resultant node for the fist line should be a node like `({name:"Bob", numbers: [4,3,3,111,5]})`? That is: name as a string property and numbers as a array of numbers property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the more elegant solution, but I have a tip to you.

First you should use a tool like [Transpose CSV Tool](http://www.convertcsv.com/transpose-csv.htm). Using this tool you can input a CSV file like:

```
Bob,Joe,Nathan
4,5,4
3,6,111
3,3,3
111,3,4
5,2,
```

And the output will be:

```
Bob,4,3,3,111,5
Joe,5,6,3,3,2
Nathan,4,111,3,4,
```

After, you can put the CSV file into the import directory and use `LOAD CSV` like this:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///convertedcsv.csv" AS line
WITH line[0] as name, filter(l IN line where l is not null) AS line
UNWIND line[1..] as number
WITH name, collect(toInteger(number)) as numbers
CREATE ({name:name,numbers:numbers})
```

In the first `WITH` the above query store the name of each line in a variable called `name` and remove all nulls of the entire line, saving the result into a variable called `line`. After, `UNWIND` gets the numbers starting from index 1 (because index 0 is the name) and save each number into `number`. Each `number` is collected into `numbers` and converted to integers.

The resultant nodes are:

```
MATCH (node) RETURN node as nodes

╒═══════════════════════════════════════╕
│"nodes"                                │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"name":"Bob","numbers":[4,3,3,111,5]} │
├───────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Nathan","numbers":[4,111,3,4]}│
├───────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Joe","numbers":[5,6,3,3,2]}   │
└───────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: thank you! so is there any way to do the same thing for strings? like if i had different domainnames associated with each name?

Comment: @KeepingCool you are welcome! Can you explain a bit more about "do the same thing for strings"? Also I suggest you to make a new question instead of use the comments.